# React-Native-Maps: How to use animateCamera and setCamera

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native and I want to animate map on particular position i'll use animateToCoordinates that deprecated and not working sometimes.

new Method for that is animateCamera but i don't get how to use that na d how to create camera object to pass in that.

thanks

Comment: whats wrong with my question why  i am getting negative votes.

Answer (score 11):

You can use animateToRegion(region,duration) by simply passing the region as

```
let region={latitude:<Target_latitude>,longitude:<Targeted_longitude>,latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,longitudeDelta:LONGITUDE_DELTA}
```

keeping Deltas fixed you can have your animation in map.

For animateToCamera you can use

```
    this.mapRef.animateCamera({center: temp_cordinate,pitch: 2, heading: 20,altitude: 200, zoom: 40},duration)
```

where type of temp_cordinate is `{latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude}`

Answer (score 4):

set ref to your mapView like this;

```
            <MapView
                ref={(map) => { this.map = map; }}
                initialRegion={this.state.region}
            />
```

then,

```
this.map.animateToRegion(region,1000)
```

call this whenever you need to update your region value

Answer (score 2):

```
<MapView
   ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
   region={{
            latitude: this.state.mapLat,
            longitude: this.state.mapLong,
            latitudeDelta: 0.001663,
            longitudeDelta: 0.002001,
    }}
    onLayout={() => {
        this.map.animateCamera({
           center: {
           latitude: this.state.mapLat,
           longitude: this.state.mapLong,
        },
           heading: 0,
           pitch: 90,
         });
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const map = useRef(null)
```

```js
    <MapView
        ref={(current) => map.current = current}
        onLayout={() => {
            map.current.animateCamera({
                pitch: 90
            })
        }}
    />
```

Comment: A short explanation of what is going on in this snippet would be great, @jay-trairat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).